# Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client()

Tags: laravel, mailhog

I'm getting an error in `mailhog` while sending an email to new user for creating password.

**Error**:

```
Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

**.env config**:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="dev@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: replace your MAIL_HOST=mailhog with MAIL_HOST=0.0.0.0

Comment: You will need to add an entry to your hosts file like this `127.0.0.1 mailhog` otherwise like others have mentioned, replace mailhog with your local IP.

I think Laravel is assuming that you are using containers out of the box.

Answer (score 6):

Do you use `sail` package for laravel? If you are using laravel sail you should set:

```
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
```

Otherwise it must be:

```
MAIL_HOST=localhost
```

Also enter a value for `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS`:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=a@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Laravel Homestead, if you take a look at the `Homestead.yml` file, almost at the top you can get the IP address set for the Homestead Virtual Machine.

Copy that address to your `.env` file and set it instead of `mailhog`:

`MAIL_HOST=192.168.56.56 #mailhog`

Then you can access Mailhog with your browser by typing

`http://192.168.56.56:8025/`

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when some changes have been made to files, specifically in .env file. I was facing the same issue and solved by this solution.

Clear cache using artisan command

```
 php artisan cache:clear
```

Clear config

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Restart your server

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

More: Try clearing browsers cache & cookies.