# Sending password reset email and getting errors

Tags: php, laravel

So I am trying to send password reset email and this is my routes for it:

```
Route::get('/password/remind', function () {
    return view('auth.password-remind');
})->name('password.remind');
Route::post('/password/remind', [RemindController::class, 'store'])->name('password.send');

Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', function () {
    return view('auth.password-reset');
})->name('password.reset');
```

And inside `RemindController` I have:

```
$data = $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => ['required', 'exists:users,email'],
            '_token' => '',
        ]);

        Mail::send('emails.password-reset', [
            'token' => $data['_token']
        ], function ($message) use ($data) {
            $message->subject('Reset Password Request');
            $message->to($data['email']);
        });
```

And then this is the email it should send:

```
Reset password <a href="{{ route('password.reset', $token) }}">here</a>
```

This is my form for sending email:

```
<form action="{{ route('password.send') }}" method="post" class="remind-form">
                <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
                <div class="form-group" error="email">
                    <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="auth-btn">Send</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

But when I submit I get errors:

```
Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

my `.env`

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myemail@gmail.com
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream\_socket\_client()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633041/connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-mailhog-stream-socket-client)

Comment: is mailhog running?  are you using laravel sail? or brew mailhog?   What is your local setup?

Answer (score 0):

hello try ssl instead tls

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myemail@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, have you set up mailhog in your device?

Set the host value should be `MAIL_HOST=mailhog` and `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null`

Then, clear your config cache after changing your `.env` file values.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

You can try mailtrap which is user-friendly

Create a mailtrap account and add these credentials and details in your `.env`

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME= (your username from mailtrap)
MAIL_PASSWORD= (your password from mailtrap)
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS= myemail@gmail.com
```

Answer (score -1):

*Clear cache using artisan command*

```
php artisan cache:clear


php artisan config:clear
```

*Restart your server*

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Still same error with this exception ```Swift_TransportException```

Comment: check your gmail id and password again

Comment: `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl`  @Edga

Comment: then runn  `php artisan cache:clear` `php artisan config:clear`